# Ηow to rename applications displayed in "Show applications" in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell, .desktop

How does one rename applications in *Show applications*? For example, how can I rename "GNU Image Manipulation Program" to "GIMP" in Ubuntu 20.04.2?

I have searched the internet and the Ask Ubuntu database, but I have found no answers. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 19):

In a terminal run:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/program-name.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/
```

Make sure sure to replace `program-name.desktop` with the correct name of the application you wish to rename.

Then, open the copied file, search for the string `Name` and change the name there.

Answer (score 16):

With the little tool `alacarte` ("Main Menu"), you can edit the launchers:

You need to install it first:

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

---

[image: alacarte screenshot]