# How to rearrange the position of icons in Show Applications (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)?

Tags: 20.04, icons, appmenu

I'd want to change the icon positions in **Show Applications**. Although *the icon is being dragged but it is not being placed where I want it to be*. Icons are ordered alphabetically, but I want to rearrange them in a different order, which I can't do because I can't drag & drop them in a certain place.
**Ubuntu** 20.04.3 LTS
**GNOME** 3.36.8
As you can see the screenshot, initially in the first row there is first *Calender* and then *Cheese* but I want first *Cheese* and then *Calender* but drag and drop not working here.
[image: Screenshot to Understand]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rename applications in "show apps", such as "GNU Image Manipulation Program" to "GIMP" 20.04.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325479/how-to-rename-applications-in-show-apps-such-as-gnu-image-manipulation-progr)

Comment: No, this is not the answer of my question.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am translating you what @24601 said, the name of the item can be changed by `alacarte` and rename 'Calendar' to 'Clendar'. That will do.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I understood what he said. I want to change the place of them as we can do in left side dock (by drag and move). In simple words Cheese shoud be placed first and then Calculator (not renaming) by drag and move. Hope you got my point.