# How do I change Nautilus name in GNOME Shell launcher (Ubuntu 21.10)?

Tags: gnome-shell, 21.10

How do I rename Nautilus name in the GNOME Shell launcher in Ubuntu 21.10? I tried to find the desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, but I can't find it anywhere for Nautilus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rename applications in "show apps", such as "GNU Image Manipulation Program" to "GIMP" 20.04.2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325479/how-to-rename-applications-in-show-apps-such-as-gnu-image-manipulation-progr)

Comment: Thank You, But the question is already answered  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Copy the Nautilus .desktop file in your home directory (replace `<username>` with your current username). Using the terminal, run the command:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop /home/<username>/.local/share/applications/
   ```

   You can edit the file directly in `/usr/share/applications` using root privileges, but it's better if you copy the .desktop file in your home: the copied file will have "priority" over the one in `/usr/share/applications` and will not be overwritten during Nautilus updates.
2. Then open the file `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` end edit the `Name` field.
3. If you are in a Xorg session, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, write `r` in the box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   If your session is Wayland, logout and login (or, if you don't care, reboot).

Comment: It Works! Thank You So much!

Comment: Neat stepwise answer; +1 also for recommending good practice here.

Comment: @vanadium thanks :-)

Comment: Do i get informed or prompted during an `apt-get upgrade` if the original `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` has changed? e.g. when the upgraded `Name` property matches my local config, the local config is still valid but redundant...

Comment: No, unfortunately you need to check it manually. You can write a script that check it for you, but it's overkill.

Comment: @LorenzKeel Or make a custom respin from nautilus' code base :)